# iOS 5: tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes for selected vs unselected state

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbaritem

The attributes set for UITabBarItem UIControlStateNormal overrides of UIControlStateSelected!

```
[navigationCtrl.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [Util colorFromHex:@"474747"], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1.0, 1.0)],  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[navigationCtrl.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [Util colorFromHex:@"FCFCFC"],UITextAttributeTextColor, nil]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Why?